# Git Workflow: Local to server

Tags: git

So I started developing something locally and turned it into a git repo. Then I took the folder and ftp'd it onto a server. Now I have SSH access to the server and git is installed. I cd'd into the folder and git said there wasn't a repo there, which I thought was stored in /.git/ and would have been uploaded with it.

I'm basically looking to add this server as a remote to be able to push to but now I'm not sure if it's setup right. Would the correct way be to clone from local first? How do you do that?

Also `git config --get remote.origin.url` isn't giving me anything on the server. I feel like I'm missing a big piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: "which I thought ... would have been uploaded with it." So.... was it?

Comment: Apparently not? That's a point of confusion for me. It kept saying it wasn't a git repo when I did `git status`

Comment: "Apparently not?" Erm... go look?

Comment: ... I did look. That's why I said "apparently not". There would be one now because I did "git init" on it. Do you have a suggestion for solving this issue? Should I try to reupload the folder from local?

Comment: Yes re-up. FTP clients typically skip hidden files by default so you may have to fiddle with your settings depending on which you're using.

Comment: I'd suggest using [``rsync``](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) if you have SSH access.

Comment: try `ls -la` to see the hidden files in your remote repo. That will tell you if your `.git` folder is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo on the server should be a "bare" repository. Do it like this:

1. `ssh` to the server and create a bare git repo:

   ```
   git init --bare /path/to/repos/project.git
   ```
2. On your local PC, add a remote like this:

   ```
   git remote add origin ssh://user@example.com/absolute/path/to/repos/project.git
   ```
3. And push to the remote for the first time:

   ```
   git push -u origin master
   ```

Notes:

- "origin" is just a common name for the main remote, you could name it anything you want, and replace that in both commands above.
- When you give the url of the remote, the path component must be absolute path on the server. For example if the repository is in your home directory, then it will look something like `ssh://user@example.com/home/user/path/to/repos/project.git`.